# Incorrect skills showing under my userid

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, jobs, users-page

I believe the technical skills that are shown below the handle are picked up from careers.stackexchange.com? However, in my case android is showing up as adobe. Please see the screenshots below:

[image: Careers likes]
[image: Users tag list]

Comment: No, you are looking at your most active tags *recently*.

Comment: The tags on the questions that I participated in? Or the questions that I posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Stack Overflow users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users) shows what top tags you were active in the selected period. The default currently is the week-to-date. You received most votes for the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [adobe](/questions/tagged/adobe) and [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) tags this week.

If you switch to the `[All]` tab, you have overall recieved most votes for the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) and [android](/questions/tagged/android) tags.

The Careers tags list you showed is a free-form list; you can edit that list and add and remove tags. It is *not* used anywhere on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks